# How to access property named as keyword 'in' in object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have part of a JavaScript object like this:

```
animation:{
    "in":{
        "effect":"flipInY"
    },
    "out":{
        "effect":"bounceOut"
    },
    "typeout":{
        "shuffle":true
    },
    "minDisplayTime":"2000",
    "loop":true
}
```

`animation` is part of a bigger object (not a simple object).
The real object is :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(datas));
```

Give:

> {"text":"example","font":"Aclonica","size":"50px","bgcolor":"#291C67","color":"#F1EC1C","align":"center","animation":{"in":{"effect":"flipInY"},"out":{"effect":"bounceOut"},"typeout":{"shuffle":true},"minDisplayTime":"2000","loop":true}}

I want to retrieve values of `animation` object to do other actions.

The special key `"in"` causes a problem here:

```
var animation=datas.animation;
if (animation.in.effect) $('#result') = animation.in.effect;
```

The error:

> TypeError: animation is not a function

If i do:

```
if (animation.out.effect) $('#result') = animation.out.effect;
```

> Result is: 'bounceOut'

How can I do that? I cannot change the keyword `"in"`.

**** Sorry i've retried tests and it works now.. thank you all. Effectively 'in' is not a special keyword..

Comment: Most probably not that line is causing you the issue. Look for places where you have `animation()`

Comment: You can try using attribute accessor like: animation["in"]

Comment: Your missing a `'` in `$('#result)`

Comment: there is not this error in my real code. Sorry i've changed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the typo (missing `'`), you can't assign to the result of a function call, so this is wrong:

```
if(animation.in.effect) $('#result') = animation.in.effect;
// ----------------------------------^ can't do that
```

You can use it as an argument to some function you call on the jQuery object you get from `$()`, e.g.:

```
if(animation.in.effect) $('#result').someFunctionhere(animation.in.effect);
```

What function that is isn't immediately clear from the question, but the main issue is trying to assign to a function call.

(Prior to ES5 in 2009, you couldn't have used `in` as a property name *literal* in that context, because `in` is a keyword. But you can as of ES5. In very old pre-ES5 environments and similar, you'd need to use `animation["in"].effect` instead. But not in any vaguely-modern web browser.)

Answer (score -1):

No, it's because you've typed wrong.

Change

```
animation: {...}
```

to

```
animation= {...}
```

Comment: maybe `animation` is part of a bigger object as well.

Comment: yes, animation is part of bigger object. Sorry i wanted to shorten the question. I've changed it in the question